Fine-tuning CodeBert for classification with more than 512 tokens
I have a dataset of SmartContracts source code written in Solidity labeled with one ore more vulnerabilities they contains.
I used the CodeBert model to classify them in a multilabel classification problem obtaining a 83% accuracy on test set.
The problem is that the CodeBert takes in input a maximum of 512 tokens so just a small initial portions of contracts, how can I input longer sequences to improve the results of my model?
I think that splitting a contract in substrings of lenght 512 is not the best solution since I'm training the model on wrong label for that subtring.
